# How much does a single request to the server cost

Tags: browser, httprequest

I was wondering how much do you win by putting all of your css scripts and stuff that needs to be downloaded in one file?

I know that you would win a lot by using sprites, but at some point it might actually hurt to do that.

For example my website uses a lot of small icons and most of the pages has different icons after combining all those icons together i might get over 500kb in total, but if i make one sprite per page it is reduced to almost 50kb/page so that's cool.

But what about scripts `js/css` how much would i win by making a script for each page which has just over ~100 lines? Or maybe i wouldn't win at all?

**Question**, basically i want to know how much does a single request cost to download a file and is it really bad to to have many script/image files with todays modern browsers and a high speed connections.

**EDIT**

Thank you all for your answers, it was hard to chose just one because every answer did answer my question, I chose to reward the one that in my opinion answered my question about request cost the most directly, I will not accept any answer as correct because everyone was.

Comment: define what you mean by *cost*

Answer (score 10):

Multiple requests means more latency, so that will often make a difference.  Exactly how *costly* that is will depend on the size of the response, the performance of the server, where in the world it's hosted, whether it's been cached, etc...  To get real measurements you should experiment with your real world examples.

I often use PageSpeed, and generally follow the documented best practices: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/about.

To try answering your final question directly: additional requests will cost more.  It's not necessarily "really bad" to have many files, but it's generally a good idea to combine content into a single file when you can.

Answer (score 8):

Your question isn't answerable in a real generic way.

There are a few reasons to combine scripts and stylesheets.

Browsers using HTTP/1.1 will open multiple connections, typically 2-4 for every host. Because almost every site has the actual HTML file and at least one other resource like a stylesheet, script or image, these connections are created right when you load the initial URL like `index.html`.

- TCP connections are costly. That's why browsers open directly multiple connections ahead of time.
- Connections are usually limited to a small number and each connection can only transfer one file at a time.

That said, you could split your files across multiple hosts (e.g. an additional `static.example.com`), which increases the number of hosts / connections and can speed up the download. On the other hand, this brings additional overhead, because of more connections and additional DNS lookups.

On the other hand, there are valid reasons to leave your files split.

The most important one is HTTP/2. HTTP/2 uses only a single connection and multiplexes all file downloads over that connection. There are multiple demos online that demonstrate this, e.g. http://www.http2demo.io/

If you leave your files split, they can also be cached separately. If you have just small parts changing, the browser could just reload the changed file and all others would be answered using `304 Not Modified`. You should have appropriate caching headers in place of course.

That said, if you have the resources, you could serve all your files separately using HTTP/2 for clients that support it. If you have a lot of older clients, you could fallback to combined files for them when they make requests using HTTP/1.1.

Comment: Good observation on HTTP2. However, we have to see that even HTTP1.1 is *keeping* connections open, instead of creating a new TCP/IP connection at each hit to the same server. HTTP1.1 also supports request pipelining, which allows answering multiple requests in parallel on the same socket - you can see it as a proof of concept for HTTP2ish connection.

Comment: @GeeBee HTTP/1.1 allows request pipelining, but this is usually server side implemented via sequential processing. (As you need to keep replies in the same order they were requested, unlike HTTP/2, where you can properly multiplex them.) The pipelining basically just is the actual implementation of keep-alive connections. Thus with HTTP/1.1 and pipelining your speed per connection is dependent on how fast the previous request was processed (if your connection is very slow, doesn't matter, but usually it does).

Comment: Again, a very good valid point. However we are talking about the network speed. If serving a request is slow on the server, there is very little we can do. Of course, HTTP/2ing multiple slow requests may work as a patch. Then after some load, the server will start running out of resources (database pool, thread pool) and we'll have much bigger problems to solve.

Answer (score 5):

Tricky question :)

Of course, the trivial answer is that more requests takes more time, but that is not necessarily this simple.

- browsers open multiple http connections to the same host, see http://sgdev-blog.blogspot.hu/2014/01/maximum-concurrent-connection-to-same.html Because that, *not* using parallel download but rather downloading one huge file is considered as a performance bottleneck by http://www.sitepoint.com/seven-mistakes-that-make-websites-slow/
- web servers shall use gzip content-encoding whenever possible. Therefore size of the text resources such as HTML, JS, CSS are quite compressed.
- most of those assets are static content, therefore a standard web server shall use etag caching on them. It means that next time the download will be like 26 bytes, since the server tells "not changed" instead of sending the 32kbyte of JavaScript over again
- Because of the etag cache, the whole web site shall be cacheable (I assume you're programming a game or something like that, not some old-school J2EE servlet page).
- I would suggest making 2-4 big files and download that, if you really want to go for the big files

So to put it together:

- if you have only static content, then it is all the same, because etag caching will shortcut any real download from the server, server returns 304 Not modified answer
- if you have some generated dynamic content (such as servlet pages), keep the JS and CSS separate as they can be etag cached separately, and only the servlet page needs to be downloaded
- check that your server supports gzip content encoding for compression, this helps a lot :)
- if you have multiple dynamic content (such as mutliple dynamically changing images), it makes sense to have them represented as 2-4 separate images to utilize the parallel http connections for download (although I can hardly imagine this use case in the real life)

Please, ensure that you're not serving static content dynamically. I.e. try to load the image to a web browser, open the network traffic view, reload with F5 and see that you get 304 Not modified from the server, instead of 200 OK and real traffic. 
The biggest performance optimization is that you don't pull anything from the server, and it comes out of the box if used properly :)

Answer (score 3):

I think @DigitalDan has the best answer.

But the question belies the real one, how do I make my page load faster? Or at least , APPEAR to load faster...

I would add something about "above the fold": basically you want to inline as much as will allow your page to render the main visible content on the first round trip, as that is what is perceived as the fastest by the user, and make sure nothing else on the page blocks that...

Archibald explains it well:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVEiIlJSx_Y

Answer (score 3):

How much you win if you use any of these types might vary based on your specific needs, but I will talk about my case: in my web application we don't combine all files, instead, have 2 types of files, common files, and per page files, where we have common files that needed globally for our application, and other files that is used for its case only, and here is why.

[image]

Above is a chart request analysis for my web application, what you need to consider is this

DNS Lookup happens only once as it cached after that, however, DNS name might be cached already, then.

On each request we have:

```
request start + initial connection + SSL negotiation+ time to first byte + content download
```

The main factor here which takes majority of request time in most cases is the content download size, so if I have multiple files that all of them needed to be used in all pages, I would combine them into one file so I can save the TCP stack time, on the other hand, if I have files needed to be used in specific pages, I would make it separate so I can save the content download time in other pages.

Answer (score 2):

Actually very relevant question (topic) that many web developer face.

I would also add my answer among other contributors of this question.

#### Introduction before going to answer

High performance web sites depending on different factors, here is some consideration:

- Website size
- Content type of website (primary content Text, image, video or mixture)
- Traffic on your website (How many people visiting your website average)
- Web-host Location vs your primary visitor location (with in your country, region and world wide), it matters a lot if you have website for Europe and your host is in US.
- Web-host server (hardware) technology, I prefer SSD disks.
- How web-server (software) is setup and optimized
- Is it dynamic or static web site
- If dynamic, how your code and database is structured and designed

By defining your need you might be able to find the proper strategy.

#### Regarding your question in general

What regards your website. I recommend you to look at Steve Souders 14 recommendation in his Book **High Performance Web Sites**.

Steve Souders 14 advice:

1. Make fewer HTTP requests
2. Use a Content Delivery Network (CDN)
3. Add an Expires Header
4. Gzip Components
5. Put Style-sheets at the Top
6. Put Scripts at the Bottom
7. Avoid CSS Expressions
8. Make JavaScript and CSS External if possible
9. Reduce DNS Lookups
10. Minify JavaScript
11. Avoid Redirects
12. Remove Duplicates Scripts
13. Configure ETages
14. Make Ajax Cacheable

#### Regarding your question

So if we take `js/css` in consideration following will help a lot:

1. It is better to have different codes on different files. 
   Example: you might have `page1`, `page2`, `page3` and `page4`. 
   `Page1` and `page2` uses `js1` and `js2` 
   `Page3` uses only `js3` 
   `Page4` uses all `js1`, `js2` and `js3` 
   So it will be a good idea to have JavaScript in 3 files. You are not interested in including every thing you have that you do not use.
2. CSS Sprites
3. CSS at top and JS at the end
4. Minifying JavaScript
5. Put your JavaScript and CSS in external files
6. CDN, in case you use jQuery for example do not download it to your website just use the recommended CDN address.

**Conclusion**

I am pretty sure there is more details to write. And not all advice are necessary to implement, but it is important to be aware of those. As I mentioned before, I suggest you reading this tiny book, it gives you more details. And finally there is no perfect final solution. You need to start some where, do your best and improved it. No thing is permanent.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

the answer to your question is it really depends.

the ultimate goal of page load optimization is to make your users *feel* your page load is fast.

some suggestions:

- do not merge common library js css files like jquery coz they might have already cached by brower when you visited other sites so u don't even need to download them;
- merge resources, but at least separate first screen required resouces and the others coz the earlier user could see some meaningful stuff, the faster they feel about your page;
- if several of your pages shared some resources, separate the merged files for shared resources and page specific resources so that when you visit the second page, the shared ones might have already been cached by browser, so the page load is faster;
- user might be using a phone with slow or inconsistent speed 3g/4g network, so even 50k of data or 2 more requests does make them feel different a lot;

Answer (score 1):

Is really bad to have a lot of 100-lines-files and is also really bad to have just one or two big files, though for each type css/js/markup.

Desktops have mostly high speed connection, and mobile has also high latency.

Taking all the theory about this topic, i think the best approach shall be more practical, less accurate and based upon actual connection speed and device types from a statistical point of view.

For example, i think this is the best way to go today:

1) put all the stuff needed to show the first page/functionality to the user, in one file, shall be under 100KB - this is absolutely a requirement.

2) after that, **split or group** the files in sizes so that the latency is no longer noticeable together with the download time.

To make it simple and concrete, if we assume: time to first byte is around ~200ms, the size of each file should be between ~120KB and ~200 KB, good for the most connections of today, averaged.